# How do I represent numeric_limits from C++ in Java?

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to write some stuff in Java by looking at the C++ class. In our C++ class, we have one variable declare like this -

```
static constexpr uint32_t NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
```

How do I write similar variable declaration in Java?

Comment: Do you need this to be exactly the same (i.e. unsigned)?

Comment: You can't, since Java doesn't have unsigned integral types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
static final int NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

The difference being that in Java, `int` is signed (as an `int32_t` then)

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

`Integer` is a wrapper class for the primitive type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could use [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) like

```
public static final int NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
static final int NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

In Java, all `Integers` are signed. If you need to represent the maximum value of an unsigned integer, you will need to use a `Long`. However, a `Long` can represent a larger value than an unsigned integer.

An `unsigned integer` can represent a maximum value of `2^32 - 1`
A `signed integer` can represent a maximum value of `2^31 - 1`
A `long` (in java) can represent a maximum value of `2^63 - 1`

You can find a full chart of data types in java and other languages here: [Integer (Computer Science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science))

If you really need the maximum value of an unsigned integer, you can do it this way (among others)

```
static final long NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = (long)Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;
```

Comment: `Math.pow(2, 63) - 1` Really? First, why do you use a floating point math function to express an integer literal constant? Express powers of two with bit-shifting instead of `Math.pow`, if you don't like literals. Secondly, the maximum value of an unsigned int (32-bit) is `2^32-1`, not `2^63-1`.

Comment: There's a number of ways this can be done (which I mentioned in my answer). Math.pow is easily readable. Efficient? Maybe not. Also, You seem to have misread a portion of my answer, as I clearly stated that an unsigned integer could represent a maximum value of 2^32-1

Comment: I was referring to "If you really need the maximum value of an **unsigned integer**"; and then you write the maximum value of a **signed long**.

Comment: That was clearly a mistake. The appropriate response to that would be to suggest an edit.

Comment: Which is what I basically did; I told you that it's `2^32-1` instead of `2^63-1`. I'm sorry if it sounded offensive; I didn't mean it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You have enough `Integer.MAX_VALUE` answers. If you need the actual value in the C++ snippet you'll need to use the 64 bit JAVA `long` since there are no unsigned integers in JAVA.
Then your code would be:

```
static final long NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = 0xffffffffl;
```

(Note the 'l' at the end for `long` literal)

This is not the same as obtaining the limits of a numeric, but might be necessary if you want to port a C++ library and retain the full functionality.